# How to loop over a valid JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have made an Ajax request to a PHP script and that PHP script returned this JSON object and when i tested with [link text](http://www.jsonlint.com/) it says it's valid

```
[
  {
    "id_annotation": "1",
    "annot_doc_id": "page_de_test.html",
    "annot_id_auteur": "2",
    "anno_startOffset": "47",
    "annot_startContainer": "id-aaa",
    "annot_endOffset": "88",
    "annot_forme": "1",
    "annot_value": "dispositif physique fait pour \n  stocker ",
    "annot_obj": "1",
    "annot_area": "",
    "annot_date": "vendredi 25 juin 2010 10:38:07"
  },
  {
    "id_annotation": "2",
    "annot_doc_id": "page_de_test.html",
    "annot_id_auteur": "2",
    "anno_startOffset": "122",
    "annot_startContainer": "id-aaa",
    "annot_endOffset": "200",
    "annot_forme": "1",
    "annot_value": " le plus simple est \n  d\u2019utiliser un syst\u00e8me de repr\u00e9sentation \u00e0 deux chiffres",
    "annot_obj": "1",
    "annot_area": "",
    "annot_date": "vendredi 25 juin 2010 10:38:19"
  },
  {
    "id_annotation": "3",
    "annot_doc_id": "page_de_test.html",
    "annot_id_auteur": "2",
    "anno_startOffset": "1",
    "annot_startContainer": "ident-77",
    "annot_endOffset": "146",
    "annot_forme": "1",
    "annot_value": "Dans un ordinateur, le dispositif qui permet de stocker de l\u2019information est donc \n  rudimentaire, bien plus rudimentaire que les mains humaines.",
    "annot_obj": "1",
    "annot_area": "",
    "annot_date": "vendredi 25 juin 2010 10:38:25"
  },
  {
    "id_annotation": "4",
    "annot_doc_id": "page_de_test.html",
    "annot_id_auteur": "2",
    "anno_startOffset": "107",
    "annot_startContainer": "ident-77",
    "annot_endOffset": "194",
    "annot_forme": "1",
    "annot_value": "crobaties avec ses doigts, mais \u00e9cartons ce cas). Avec un \n  emplacement d\u2019information ",
    "annot_obj": "1",
    "annot_area": "",
    "annot_date": "vendredi 25 juin 2010 10:38:33"
  }
]
```

But the problem was when i tried ti loop over this json response by using this function, the fonction get excuted just one time, I want to know how to loop over this returned JSON

```
success: function(data) {
  var mon_selection_2;
  var mon_range;
  resultText = eval(data);
  var resultText_length = resultText.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < resultText_length; i++) {
    mon_selection_2 = window.getSelection();
    mon_selection_2.removeAllRanges();
    mon_range = document.createRange();
    mon_selection_2.addRange(mon_range);
    id_annotation_js = resultText[i].id_annotation;
    anno_startOffset_js = resultText[i].anno_startOffset;
    annot_startContainer_js = resultText[i].annot_startContainer;
    annot_endOffset_js = resultText[i].annot_endOffset;
    annot_value_js = resultText[i].annot_value;
    annot_forme_js = resultText[i].annot_forme;
    var start_Node = document.getElementById(annot_startContainer_js);
    var textNode = start_Node.firstChild;
    mon_range.setStart(textNode, anno_startOffset_js);
    mon_range.setEnd(textNode, annot_endOffset_js);
    var Gras_ele_js = document.createElement("span");
    Gras_ele_js.setAttribute("style", "color:black;font-size:14px;font-weight:bolder");
    Gras_ele_js.setAttribute("value", mon_range);
    Gras_ele_js.setAttribute("id", id_annotation_js);
    mon_range.surroundContents(Gras_ele_js);
  }
}
```

Comment: You most probably don't need to use `eval()` Can you show the whole `ajax()` call?

Comment: If the `data` parameter is a JSON string, then he will need to either use eval or a different parser (like `JSON.parse`) to deserialize it.

Comment: If the loop is running only once, then something is crashing inside the loop. Have you tried using developer tools to look for errors in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, with this line

```
resultText = eval(data);
```

you convert the string into a javascript object. You shouldn't do it that way (using eval), even if it's the fastest of all ways, because if massive security reasons.

You **should** use jQuerys very own implementation `$.parseJSON()` or, if available, browsers integrated `JSON` parser like `window.JSON.parse()`;

To your question, you need to loop over an object here.

```
$.each(resultText, function(i,v)){
   $.each(v, function(index,value){
      anno_startOffset_js = value.anno_startOffset;
      // or anno_startOffset_js = value['anno_startOffset'];
   });
};
```

Comment: Sorry and thank you 
But for example how to get How to get "anno_startOffset" value in every loop of resulText and save it in variable?

Comment: @access2008, and remember to always `var` your variables, especially when dealing with closures :)